# GraphQL Where Select Sub Query

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

These day, i have studied `GraphQL` with `Laravel` framework, Lighthouse Library.
I have tried to do kind of `SELECT Query`.

As a result, I wonder GraphQL can select below SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE type=1 AND chart_id=(SELECT id FROM TABLE_B WHERE phone='0000~~')
```

I expect, Client first get result from this query.

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE_B WHERE phone='0000~~'
```

And then Do Second query, i think i can get a result.

But i wonder I can get result from 1 request. Thanks.

Comment: is there any relation between `tableA` and `tableB`??

Comment: @MikeRoss Yes. TableA has foreign key which name is chart_id. chart_id is the key of TableB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```
 $phoneNumber = '0000~~';

 $data = DB::table('tableA')->where('type',1)
            ->whereIn('chart_id',function($query) use ($phoneNumber) {
                $query->select('id')
                      ->from('tableB')
                     ->where('phone', '=',$phoneNumber);
         })->get();
```

If there is relationship between `tableA` and `tableB` you can do following

```
 TableA::where('type',1)
        ->whereHas('tableBRelationshipName', function ($q) use ($phoneNumber) {
             $q->select('id')
             $q->where('phone','=',$phoneNumber);
 })->get();
```